# How to create a button to add items to cart?

Tags: html, django, django-views, django-templates, pycharm

[This is the page I have created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKJdC.jpg)

This is the views.py file:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Pizza
# Create your views here.


def index(request):

    pizzas = Pizza.objects.all().order_by('price')
    context = {
        'pizzas': pizzas
    }
    return render(request, 'menu/index.html', context)
```

And this is the index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> {% load static %}
<html lang="en">


<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <title>Our Pizzas</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'menu/style.css' %}">
</head>
<body>
<a href="{% url 'main:index' %}"><img id='logo' src="{% static 'menu/images/small_logo.png' %}"></a>
    <h1>Our Pizzas</h1>
    <ul>
        {% for pizza in pizzas %}
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td id="one" ><b>{{pizza.name}}</b></td><td id="two">{{pizza.price | floatformat:2}}$</td>
            </tr>
        </table>

            <li id="ing">{{pizza.ingredients}}</li>
            {% if pizza.vegetarian %}

            <li style="background-color:#DD7835;
padding:3px;
width:90px;
font-size:13px;
text-align:center;
border-radius:10px;
font-weight:bold;
" >VEGETARIAN</li>

            {% endif %}

        {% endfor %}

    </ul>

</body>
</html>
```

How can I add buttons on my page where the user can add the pizzas to cart and the data is stored in the /admin page?

this is my admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Pizza

class PizzaAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name','ingredients','vegetarian','price')
    search_fields = ['name']
admin.site.register(Pizza, PizzaAdmin)
# Register your models here.
```

At the backend, the quantity of pizzas that the customer has ordered should be visible.

Comment: It looks to me like your HTML is invalid. The first element after the `<ul>` is `<table>` and that is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

First you will need to update the PizzaAdmin to include the quantity ordered.

Then you can do a POST request to a new path like add_to_cart that updates the database and reloads the index page

`views.py`

```
def add_to_cart(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    pizza_id = request.POST['pizza_id']
    pizza = Pizza.objects.get(id=pizza_id)
    
    # Create a new order object and save it to the database
    order = Order(pizza=pizza)
    order.save()

return redirect('main:index')
```

`urls.py`

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'main'

urlpatterns = [
  path('', views.index, name='index'),
  path('add_to_cart/', views.add_to_cart, 
  name='add_to_cart'),
  # Other URL mappings
]
```

`html`

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'main:add_to_cart' %}">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <input type="hidden" name="pizza_id" value="{{ pizza.id }}">
                <button type="submit">Add to Cart</button>
            </form>
```

Comment: I am new to Django so please explain what changes should I make to PizzaAdmin

Comment: Add this: ```quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0)```
After changing this you will need to migrate database, you'll have to provide default values to make sure the code works.